# Difference between assist in and assist?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in the meaning between "assist in" and "assist" ?

Suppose Kim went to a foreign country and lost Kim's wife.

```
1) The policeman assists Kim in finding Kim's wife

2) The policeman assists Kim finding Kim's wife
```

Does 1) sentence mean "Kim lost his wife. and Kim calls the police. The policeman arrives at Kim. The policeman is trying to find Kim's wife  (Kim is not trying to find Kim's wife. Kim only waits at the police station for the police to come with his wife. )" ?

Does 2) sentence mean "Kim lost his wife. and Kim is finding Kim's wife. Kim does not find Kim's wife. and Kim calls the police. The policeman arrives at Kim. The policeman and Kim is trying to find Kim's wife " ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**assists** can be transitive or intransitive.

When it is transitive it takes a direct object.

> They assisted the surgeon.

When it is intransitive, there is no direct object, but there can be a complement which presents the context of the assistance and shows the nature of their assistance:

> They assisted in the search.

They, too, searched.

When it is transitive, it can take both a direct object and a complement which presents the context of the assistance:

> They assisted the surgeon in the delicate surgical procedure.

The pattern is:

To assist with {some activity}  <sup>intransitive</sup>

To assist in {some activity}  <sup>intransitive</sup>

To assist {someone}  {with | in}  {some activity} <sup>transitive</sup>

The problem with your second example is that **finding Kim's wife** is not a good complement for **assist** since it is not introduced with an appropriate preposition, such as **with** or **in**.

Lacking such a preposition, the participle phrase **finding Kim's wife** is understood to complement Kim, identifying what Kim is doing:

> They assisted Kim  looking for his wife.

The statement above is grammatical, but because it gets interference from the **assist with |in** pattern, it is sub-optimal in its reduced form, that is, without **who was**. It would be better to say:

> They assisted Kim, who was looking for his wife.

That is, they gave help to Kim. Their assistance might have been to join in the search, or it might have been to fix a flat tire on Kim's car.  If you want to state unambiguously that they, too, took part in the search:

> They assisted Kim in looking for his wife.
>
> They assisted Kim with the search for his wife.

Comment: I feel something a little bit.  Does "They assisted Kim in looking for his wife." mean "They assisted Kim + They assisted in looking for his wife" ?

Comment: @user22046. They joined Kim's search and in doing so assisted him.  They assisted Kim by searching.  The context and nature of their assistance is given in the complement.    "+" is a mathematical operator, not an English word, so it is not clear what you mean by it here. They are not doing two things, but one thing: they are joining in Kim's search and he is a beneficiary of their efforts.

Comment: Does "They assisted Kim in looking for his wife" mean 
"They assisted Kim. What they assisted Kim was looking for his wife"? Does "in" in the sentence mean " What they assisted Kim " ?

Comment: @user22046: The prepositional phrase introduced by **in** specifies the nature and context of the assistance provided to Kim.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first choice is correct, however your sentence:

- *The policeman assist Kim in finding Kim's wife*

is wrong.

It ought to be like:

- The policeman **assists** Kim **in**/**with** finding **his** wife

OR:

- The **policemen/police** **assist** Kim **in**/**with** finding **his** wife

Comment: What is the meaning of "in" over there?

I can understand the meaning of "in" in "a ball in the box". However, I rarely understand the meaning of "in" in sentences with "in ~ ing". I want to understand the meaning of the preposition "in" in "in ~ ing".

Comment: Wel, it's simple. Like you say "Can you **help** me with doing my homeworks**?" In The same way you say **assist someone in doing something**.

Comment: I can not understand anything if it is explained in terms that I can not understand. I would appreciate it if you could explain it through an easy expression that I can understand. I rarely understand the meaning of "in" in sentences with "in ~ ing". I would appreciate it if you could explain it in a sentence without the phrase "in ~ ing".

Comment: Alright, then please take a look at this definition, from the macMillan dictionary: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/assist_1

Comment: the first definiton is what you search for

Comment: If you'd like to use the verb "assist" **without in**, you must use the verb infinitive. For example: "*We want to **assist students to take more responsibility** for their work.*"

Comment: Does "The policeman assists Kim in finding his wife" mean "The policeman assists Kim to help Kim with finding his wife" ? Does "in" in "in ~ing" mean "to help someone to ~ing" ?

Comment: Well, sorta yes! However, like I menetioned earlier, your structure is wrong. You should use "Help someone do something" (without to).

Comment: RE: _What is the meaning of this "in"? I can understand the meaning of "in" in "a ball in the box"..._ Like many [other](http://www.wordnik.com/words/on) little prepositions, the word "in" has [several](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida) different meanings, and many of them are a bit abstract, such as when we say phrases like, "in relation to," "in contrast," "in order to," "in other words," "in love," "in rhythm," "in step with," "in cash," "in English," and "[In-a-gadda-da-vida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida)." (That last one was said in jest.)